# 404 Not Found server not responding

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, bower

I have a angular 1.5 project that uses bower, that I'm trying to view on my local machine. Every time I launch the project in a browser I get a 404 error server not found. What should I do to resolve this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5EbX.png)PS I have Node, npm, and bower install.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the project? Normally, dependencies are put in some place and access through static path.

Comment: @LucasCosta can you be a little more specific when your referring to the structure ? Are you referring to technologies used  or file path ?

Comment: You need a lot more information besides "help, it doesn't work".  How are you building the app?  How are you referencing your bower components?  Are you using gulp/grunt/webpack?

Comment: @VtoCorleone this was a prototype build by someone else. However, they are using Angular 1.5 , using bower, and using gulp to reference the components. Karma js, is being used as a test running script as well. I need to access the application on my machine and view.

Comment: Did they have the prototype working on their machine?  Have you tried running `npm install` and `bower install`?  It looks like your bower_components aren't found which leads me to believe you need to run `bower install` to get the components.

Comment: I've ran npm install and $ npm install -g bower @VtoCorleone

Comment: But have you ran `bower install`?  `npm install` installs all of your npm dependencies.  `bower install` installs all of your bower dependencies.  Look in your source for a bower_components directory and see if it has your dependencies in it.

Comment: Yes my bower_components has dependencies, remember this was a project already build. I just need it to get working on my machine locally. Can you provide the bower ran command? @VtoCorleone